# What does it mean to 暑苦しく語る?

Tags: meaning

> 同人について暑苦しく語り過ぎたんでしょう？それで相手をドン引きさせてしまって

How does 暑苦しく work here? The first thought I had was that it meant passionate, but 熱 is the one associated with passionate, not 暑.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[暑]{あつ}[苦]{くる}しい means "hot, damp and suffocating / uncomfortable."

If someone says 「暑苦しい」 in a muggy summer afternoon, s/he describes the physical feeling in the weather.

暑苦しい is also used to describe mental feelings in some situations, like the case of the sentences in your question.

The nuance of [暑]{あつ}[苦]{くる}しく[語]{かた}る is that the speaker talks very passionately, and her/his eager attitude changes the atmosphere in which the listener feels very uncomfortable because it's too intense for the listener.

In Japanese language, [暑]{あつ}い is used to express a warm/hot **air** temperature, while [熱]{あつ}い is used to express all other kinds of warm/hot temperatures.

So, in the physical-feeling case above, someone says 「暑苦しい」 using 暑, because the high air temperature and the high humidity are making the person feel uncomfortable.

And in the mental-feeling case in which the speaker did 「暑苦しく語り過ぎた」, the listener felt that the speaker's emitted extreme passion had been traveling through the air (toward the listener) changing the atmosphere there, then the listener felt 「暑苦しい」 about the atmosphere and the source of 「暑苦しさ」 which is the speaker's passion, or attitude, or both.

Answer (score 1):

暑苦しい means the temperature is too high and offensive, in this case, how he talks is pushy.

Comment: Grammar-wise, how does this work? I have found that turning i-adjectives into く works similar to using na adjectives with に when using them as adverbs, so would it be something like に's definition as 変化の対象 in このぶどうはぶどう酒にするのです?

Comment: It's different from adverbial forms of na adjective. このぶどうはぶどう酒にするのです = we will make this grape into wine.

Comment: But saying このぶどうはぶどう熱くするのです seems to work the same way in that it says "we will make this grape hot."

Comment: What it looks like doesn't necessarily mean what it is.

Comment: Could you tell me how it works then? From what my viewpoint it seems to work the exact same way but the i adjective turning to く instead of using に. I can't seem to come up with a grammatical explanation on why 暑苦しく語る translates to pushy.

Comment: ぶどう酒に is "into wine" but きれいに is not "into cleanness".